# Delete rows in columns V and Y if it meets these conditions

Tags: python, xlsx

I'm trying to delete rows in columns V and Y in a xlsx if the cell values meets the criteria specified. For example, read column V, if the cell values are 2 or 3 and if column Y cell value is "Undisclosed"

I have a python code that opens the file, reads the rows one by one but it doesn't delete the rows with in the criteria mentioned above.

```
import openpyxl

def delete_rows_with_conditions(file_path, sheet_name):
    # Load the workbook
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

    # Select the specified sheet
    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]

    # Get the header values
    headers = [cell.value for cell in sheet[1]]

    # Iterate over the rows in reverse order to avoid skipping rows after deletion
    for row in reversed(range(2, sheet.max_row + 1)):  # Start from row 2 assuming headers are in row 1
        # Check condition for deletion based on header value and cell value
        if (headers[21] == 'Count' and sheet.cell(row, 22).value in [2, 3]) and \
           (headers[24] == 'Com' and sheet.cell(row, 25).value == 'Undisclosed'):
            sheet.delete_rows(row)

    # Save the modified workbook
    workbook.save(file_path)

    # Close the workbook
    workbook.close()


# Usage example
file_path = 'C:/filename.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'sheet2'

delete_rows_with_conditions(file_path, sheet_name)
# Usage example
```